# How do I convert a String of digits into separate digits and add them together in Java?

Tags: java, string, integer, digits

I am kind of new to coding, and I need some help. What I'm trying to do is to make the user input an expression of this type: +(1 2 3). It should return (1+2+3) --> 6. However, for some reason when I do this, it returns "150".

The code is in spanish, however, it's pretty simple to understand. Ignore every other declared variable.

```
public void evaluar(){
    // TODO Arreglar suma
    Visualizador v = new Visualizador();
    Node n = new Node();
    String criterio = "";
    criterio = v.DarExp("Ingrese la expresion");
    int total = 0;
    int suma = 0;
    int resta = 0;
    int multiplicacion = 1;
    int division = 1;
    if (criterio.charAt(0) == '+'){
        criterio = criterio.replace("(", "");
        criterio = criterio.replace(")", "");
        criterio = criterio.replace("+", "");
        criterio = criterio.replace(" ", "");
        total = Integer.parseInt(criterio);
        System.out.println(total);
        for (int i = 0; i < criterio.length(); i++){
            suma += criterio.charAt(i);
        }
        System.out.println(suma);
    }
```

Comment: You are adding ascii values by using charAt.

Answer (score 0):

try `suma += criterio.charAt(1) - '0';`
The reason is: `'1'`, the character, is different from `1`, the integer. Check ASCII table and you will see what I'm talking about.

Comment: Thanks a ton! By far the easiest solution. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It is adding the ascii value of the char

consider

```
   String criterio = "+123";

    if (criterio.charAt(0) == '+'){
        criterio = criterio.replace("(", "");
        criterio = criterio.replace(")", "");
        criterio = criterio.replace("+", "");
        criterio = criterio.replace(" ", "");
        int suma = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < criterio.length(); i++){
            suma += criterio.charAt(i) - '0';
        }
        System.out.println(suma);
    }
```

Comment: I would, but the user has to input the String he wants, it can't be predefined. I managed to fix it though, thank you =)

Comment: I meant use the method of my code to fix your problem.  You are not a baby and I am not a baby-sitter

Answer (score 0):

In Java, a `char` is an integer, which means it has an integral value, and can be converted to int in arithmetic expressions.

- `'1'` equals 49
- `'2'` equals 50
- `'3'` equals 51

And the sume of 49, 50 and 51 is 150!

You can use `Character.getNumericValue()` to get the correct value for these characters.

```
suma += Character.getNumericValue(criterio.charAt(i));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your solution will fail when having a digit greater than 10.

Try `split` by `" "` and sum of tokens:

```
    String criterio = "+(1 2 3)";
    int suma = 0;
    if (criterio.charAt(0) == '+'){
        criterio = criterio.replace("(", "");
        criterio = criterio.replace(")", "");
        criterio = criterio.replace("+", "");
        String[] tokens = criterio.split(" ");
        for (String s : tokens) {
            suma += Integer.parseInt(s);
        }
        System.out.println(suma);
    }
```

Or better with java 8:

```
suma = Arrays.stream(tokens).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).sum();
```

Comment: Thank you, though I found it easier to do it with the other solutions. I don't really get what are the tokens for x__X